# spherical coordinates cross prodct

Tags: coordinate-systems, classical-mechanics

On the one hand, |$\hat{z} \times \vec{r}| = |r(\hat{z} \times \hat{r})|=rsin\theta $. direction ???

On the other hand, $\hat{z} \times \vec{r}=r\hat{z}\times({\hat{\rho}+\hat{z})} = r\hat{\varphi}$.

Generally I want to calculate $\hat{z} \times \vec{r}$ but I seem to get different answers in different method. What have I done wrong?

*$\rho$ is the radial component in cylindrical coordinates. $\phi$ is the azimuth angle and $\theta$ the polar angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the second line: because you assumed $\vec{r} = r \hat{\rho} + r\hat{z}$ (which is clearly false because the length of the LHS is $r$, while on the RHS it is $\sqrt{2}r$). The correct equation is
\begin{align}
\vec{r} = (r \sin \theta)\, \hat{\rho} + (r \cos \theta)\, \hat{z}
\end{align}
If you plug this in, there's no contradiction anymore. The direction of the cross product $\hat{z} \times \vec{r}$ is
\begin{align}
\hat{\phi}&= -\sin \phi \, \hat{x} + \cos \phi \, \hat{y}
\end{align}